# Can/Should I uninstall an old, manually-installed version of PyCharm after updating it?

Tags: pycharm

I was using (a manually-installed) PyCharm Community 2020.1.5, but I wanted to update it to the newest version, so I first tried to do this using the "Update Now" (or something similar, I forgot, it was in the bottom-right). However, this took me to the webpage to re-install PyCharm, so I figured I would just install Toolbox and update via that instead. After I opened Toolbox and updated PyCharm, it seems like I now have the correct version (2020.3.3) which works fine, but I still have the old version as well. So, two questions: Is this old version taking up a significant amount of extra space on my computer, and can I safely uninstall it without losing anything? If it is helpful, I am using Windows 10.

Thanks in advance.

[(This is a screenshot of the Toolbox menu. I'm really not sure how helpful it will be, though)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3BxC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete old config directories. Please follow [IDEA-165872](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165872) (Toolbox specific: [TBX-706](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-706)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there would be an issue deleting it.
[Here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000742090-Remove-old-PyCharm-after-upgrade) is the JetBrains official Page answering this question